# Excel Change Columns Based On Another One

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently working on 6 Excel workbooks all with same format. Basicly i have a table which includes product codes with their amount needs to be used. I have around 200 worksheets in every Excel file with same format. I want to update these product amount based on multiplier table i made. Here an example of data below;

Sample of data

[image]

Multiplier table

[image]

So the new values of sample codes should be 4,15 3,5 7,84 and 88,62.

Because the high amount of pages with workbooks, probably changing or inserting some kind of formula one by one would take very long time. I wonder how can I get the job done with few easy steps.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? What you mean by saying: 200 pages?

Comment: I couldn't tried anything yet because I don't know any possible solution other than change every amout one by one or insert a formula in each record.

Because my Excel not in English I probably wrongly translated the term. I checked it from Google and right term should be Worksheet. Thanks for pointing that out.

I stuck at updating amount column with multiplier value from table I made. Every amount row should be multiply with the code contains its product code.

Comment: either you change it manually or create VBA program to done this automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked some guides for basics of VBA and created my own VBA script. It became a little hardcoded but because this is one time job, it get the job done.

```
Sub degistir()
    Dim WS_Count As Integer
         Dim I As Integer
         Dim val As Double



         WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count


         For I = 1 To WS_Count
            Worksheets(I).Activate

            For R = 8 To 14
                val = ActiveSheet.Cells(R, 4)

                If ActiveSheet.Cells(R, 2) Like "P001" Then
                val = val * 1
                ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(R, 2) Like "P002" Then
                val = val * 0.533333333
                'and goes...
                End If



                ActiveSheet.Cells(R, 4).Value = val


            Next R
         Next I
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to use [VLookup function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd797422(v=office.12).aspx) or [array formula](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/275165/when-to-use-a-sum-if-array-formula). Then you'll be able to fill down or copy formula for every single record.

In your case i'd suggest to use array formula. Assuming, if `MultiplierTable` is the name of worksheet and that worksheet contains data (as you provided) in a range `C4:D7`, you can copy below formula and paste it into `E4` cell:

```
=D4*SUM(IF(C4=MultiplierTable!C$4:C$7,MultiplierTable!D$4:D$7,0))
```

Fill down the formula. Select entire column and paste as values in the same column. Repeat this step for each worksheet.

Follow the links for further details.

In case, you want to use VBA, please let me know. I'll try to improve my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Using a formula like VLOOKUP could be useful but due to high amount of Worksheets it would take repetitive copy&paste process. I have 6 excel files and each one contains around 200 worksheets. Every worksheet need to be edited so i guess this will require more than 1000 copy&paste process. A VBA script to multiply C column with multiplier which equal to product ID on B column could be more useful and time saving. I have total 12 different products and they repeats in different combinations but every productID is unique in thier worksheet.

Comment: @Ilhan, have you at least a minimum of experience with VBA? If not, i'm affraid you won't be able to change the code to your needs. Assuming, you need to hire freelancer or am i wrong?

Comment: I have C# experience but never wrote VB or Microsoft Office script. Since VBA is easy to read o guess i can make necessary changes.

Comment: You tagged your question Excel-VBA, so i thought that you're unexperienced. So, you may write C# programme.There are 2 options: 1) using Interop or 2) using OleDb. Which is more familiar to you?

Comment: I'm unexperienced in just VBA. If I had Visual Studio here at work, I can create an seperate Desktop Application to get the job done but this is last option because this needs a bit work at home. So finally I think i can edit any VBA macro to if it does anything close to my question.